# FabricJS custom fonts render incorrectly on node-canvas

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, fabricjs, cairo, node-canvas

I'm hitting a brick wall when it comes to getting custom fonts working with FabricJS / node-canvas in AWS Lambda. The fonts are loading but when they are rendered to the canvas they are completely mutilated and appear on a single line instead of multiple. The letter spacing (kerning) is also messed up and the issue may be because of this...?

In Browser:

[image: FabricJS in browser]

Server Side (AWS Lambda + node-canvas + FabricJS)

[image: Fabric JS with AWS Lambda and node-canvas]
Does anyone have even the vaguest of ideas as to what is going on here? I've tried changing the charSpacing and that doesn't work :( I know that an exact replica of what can be seen in the browser can be rendered in node-canvas as another service is doing the same thing with FabricJS...

I would be forever grateful for any help on this! And thanks in advance!!!

Kyle

Based on another SO question ([character width calculation wrong with some font which can make auto indent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998842/character-width-calculation-wrong-with-some-font-which-can-make-auto-indent)) I tried `fabric.util.clearFabricFontCache();`
but this had no effect.

Node-canvas version: 2.6.1

FabricJS version: 3.6.3

Through process of elimination - I believe that the textbox font / font family details are being cached. I've removed the custom fonts from being loaded and I'm still getting the custom font rendered... I've used the clearFabricFontCache() after loadFromJSON and it's still showing the custom font!

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same issue. I followed this approach:

```
  fabric.nodeCanvas.registerFont(__dirname + '/test/fixtures/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf', {
    family: 'Ubuntu', weight: 'regular', style: 'normal'
  });
```

and everything worked.

Ref.: [Custom fonts in Fabric on Node](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4#node)